# How to create a delivery area/zone with Google maps or apple maps on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

How I can create a delivery area/zone?

For example if the customer isn’t in the delivery zone he can’t order and if he is inside he can!

![image]

Comment: 1. Set the center of the delivery area as coordinates.  2. Get user's coordinates.  3. Get the distance between them.  4. If the distance exceeds the maximum travel distance, show the message.  Don't say "I want code."

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. No worries I don’t search any code but some help ! And right now it’s more clear for me. Have a great night